# How to ensure previous checkbox is checked to enable current checkbox

Tags: checkbox, slim-lang

I am trying to perform validations on coffeescript to enable the checkbox only if the previous checkbox is checked for a list of tasks. My current codes are below.

```
    - @job.tasks.each do |task|
     - if (not @job.started?) || @job.final_price.zero?
      .checkbox
     - elsif task.completed?
      .checkbox.enable
        i.checkmark.icon
     -else
      = link_to '', complete_gogetters_task_path(task), method: 'put', class: 'checkbox enable', id:"ck_submit1", onclick: 'Form_one()', num: task.id
```

How to I find the previous task? I want to do something like:

```
    - @job.tasks.each do |task|
     - if (not @job.started?) || @job.final_price.zero? || task.prev.not_completed?
      .checkbox
     - elsif task.completed?
      .checkbox.enable
        i.checkmark.icon
     -else
      = link_to '', complete_gogetters_task_path(task), method: 'put', class: 'checkbox enable', id:"ck_submit1", onclick: 'Form_one()', num: task.id
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, where does coffeescript come into play here? I don't see any coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to do it using ***each_with_index*** and put the index in checkbox id (for example ***:id => "checkbox_#{index}"***) and data value (***:data => index***).

Clicking by any checkbox get ***index = (this).attr('data')*** and enable next by ***$("#checkbox_#{index+1}").removeAttr("disabled")***
Of course in file with COFFEE that we can't see here.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. Will try it out :)